# noUiSlider touch events not working in foundation off-canvas menu

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, nouislider

I am using noUiSlider in a Foundation 6 off-canvas menu, and the slider handles will not drag on touch devices. It works if the noUiSlider is nested outside of the off-canvas menu, and it even works fine in the off-canvas menu when using a mouse to drag the handles. However when I emulate touch events, or actually attempt to drag the sliders handles on a touch device the slider handles do not move and stay fixed in place.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="off-canvas position-right" id="offCanvasNestedPush" data-content-scroll="false" data-off-canvas>
    <div class="row align-middle" id="fr_wrapper_price_slider" data-initial-start="0" data-initial-end="10000000">
        <div class="columns small-12">
            <!-- noUiSlider -->
            <div id="fr_price_slider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var fr_price_slider_wrapper = document.getElementById('fr_wrapper_price_slider');
var fr_price_slider = document.getElementById('fr_price_slider');
noUiSlider.create(fr_price_slider, {
    /* Slider Positions on DOM Load */
    start: [
        fr_price_slider_wrapper.getAttribute('data-initial-start'),
        fr_price_slider_wrapper.getAttribute('data-initial-end')
    ],
    behaviour: 'drag',
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': [ 0, 5000 ],
        '50%': [ 1000000, 50000 ],
        'max': [ 10000000 ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason i'm answering this question myself is because I was not able to find any questions on StackOverflow that asked about this issue, and it's a really simple fix. Foundation 6's documentation for the off-canvas menu does not mention that setting `data-content-scroll="false"` can block touch events for third-party scripts nested in the off-canvas menu. I spent far more time than I should have debugging this issue, and I'm hoping it will save someone some time in the future.

**Bugfix:**

Remove the `data-content-scroll="false"` attribute from the off-canvas menu element, and noUiSlider will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found out the contentScroll option is responsible for this because it prevents touch events if enabled. Your 'bugfix' is not a real solution because this option has a right to exist!

There are use cases (for example in my projects) where you need it.
However a solution would be an additional option for the noUiSlider which provides the possibility to change the slider's scope.

I've submitted a PR for this last year which has not been merged yet
https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/pull/821